# Android XML layout removing a layout messes everything up?

Tags: android, xml, layout

Hello there I have this layout that I need to take out currently from my app.
The problem I am encountering right now is when I remove it , it causes everything to fail but I am unsure why.  I tried to decipher it but im confused , help.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/checkInBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="18dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/num"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/qooway_m"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/checkInButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button"
            android:text="@string/check"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Without seeing the log telling us what is causing the crash it is impossible to tell. I can tell you, however, that somewhere your app is trying to use that layout directly.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the ID was used else where

Thanks~!